# How to run Google CTS on multiple device?

Tags: android, cts

I have connected 2 devices on my machine and I want to run Google CTS in both the devices.
But here the problem is, Whenever I run ./startcts command, both the devices are getting connected to the session.

My Requirement:

1. I want to run CTS in both the devices.
2. Its ok if it requires two separate android-cts folder paths.
3. Is it possible to make one device to connect one android cts session?

I have gone through the startcts and host-config files. But did not find any places to modify.
Since I am new to the CTS, can anyone please help me if they have solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Possible,

modified `./startcts` file or make your modifies script file, then pass the device id as scripts argument. (As many as you want)

And put or modified command, (put different device is in this command)

```
start --plan test_plan_name -t/--test test_name -d/--device device_ID:
```

run a specific test using the specified device.

Also look at http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cts-manual.pdf

AS CTS image say itself:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To shard a plan test run on multiple devices
'run cts --plan CTS --shards

**For latest versions as Android 7 and 8 :**
'run cts --shards [number of devices]

**Running CTS with specific devices:**
run cts --shards [number of devices] -s [device slno] [device slno]